# How to filter an array for multiple values using NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following array of data:

```
NSArray *denoms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"$1", @"$1.5", @"$2", @"c2.5", @"c10", @"$100", @"$51", nil];
```

If I try to search following string in array then it should return me the exact values out of the array if exist.

For e.g. `@"$1,$100"` then result should be

```
$1
$100
```

How to filter in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", @"$1,$100"];
```

<sub>I used to get the solution while posting the question. So keep it for future references.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

this is code. it is working for me

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:filter, @"SELF", @"a"];
```